# Update modal data after partial view refresh

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller

I have a select box in a main view. That view has inside a partial view. **When the value on that select box changes I want to reload the partial view (with some new data from a model) and update a modal content with that new data**.

I can reload the partial view successfully, my problem is What is the best approach for the modal update?

Options I see:

- define the modal in the main view but don't know how to access the data from the model passed to the partial view;
- define the modal inside partial view but is this a good practice?
- pass the model with all information to the main view, but this way, when the value on the select box changes I need to refresh all the view, and I prefer to reload only the partial view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I understand from you question is that, you have a main view which has a SelectList control on selection change of that the SelectList you want to update a portion of view (the partial view), for that portion you may be using a partial view. If that is the case follow the following steps, hopefully this will help you in achieving your task:

Step: 1:
lets say this is your main view
[MainView.cshtml]

```
@model yourProjectNameSpace.SomeModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>@ViewBag.Title</h2>

<select id='yourSelectList'>
  <option value="1">Option One</option>
  <option value="2">Option two</option>
</select>

<div id="PartialAreaToUpdate">
    @Html.Partial("_YourPartialView", Model)
</div>

@section scripts
{
<script>
        $('#yourSelectList').change(function () {
            var selectedvalue = $(this).val();
            if (!selectedvalue ) {
                return;
            }
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetYourUpdatedPartial", "YourControllerName")',
                data: { selectedvalue: selectedvalue},
                success: function (response) {
                     $('#PartialAreaToUpdate').html('');
                     $('#PartialAreaToUpdate').html(response);
                }
            });
        });
</script>
}
```

step.2: your controller code will look like

```
    public class YourControllerNameController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult GetYourUpdatedPartial(string selectedvalue)
        {
            var model = getUpdtedDataFromYOurStor(selectedValue);
            return View("_YourPartialView", model);
        }
    }
```

step. 3: Finally
your partial view [ _YourPartialView.cshtml ]

```
@model yourModel

your logic of rendering data will go here
```